# iPhone sends iMessage, but doesn't show that it was "delivered", even though it is

Tags: iphone, messages

So after switching to my new iPhone 6s, I have been sending messages through iMessage. I haven't had any major issues. What has occurred though is that the messages send with the blue bubble (informing me that they are sending as iMessages) and the recipient receives the message and is able to respond without any issue. But the actual messages never displays the words "delivered" under them. While this isn't a major issue as they are sending without any problem, I am wondering why the words "delivered" do not show up.

P.S. the words "delivered" appear for the recipient when they respond to me.

Comment: How are they being sent - via SMS or another way?

Comment: Are they blue messages? Green messages can't say delivered.

Comment: They are being sent through Imessage. they are blue messages, and they send without issue, and the recipient receives them without issue, it just for some reason does not say delivered, even though they are receiving them.

Comment: You are aware that the title of your question doesn't make sense?

Comment: I get exactly the same problem! I send an iMessage from my iPhone 6s, the recipient receives it, but the blue bubble never shows that it's "delivered". The message shows up on my linked Mac's iMessage. If I send a message from iMessage on the Mac, it shows its status is "delivered".

Now here's the weird bit. When the recipient *reads* the message, it shows that it was Read on both iPhone 6s and Mac.

Comment: My (identical) problem magically resolved itself this morning.

Answer (score 1):

> iMessage lets you send free text, photo, and video messages to other
>   iOS and OS X users anywhere in the world . Read receipts allow your
>   contacts to see whether or not you've viewed a message. While some
>   people may consider read receipts to be a bit stalker-ish, others may
>   find them useful for work and business situations. Regardless of why
>   you need them, we can help you turn them on or off no matter what iOS
>   device or Mac you're using.

http://www.imore.com/how-turn-and-read-receipts-imessage

Just ask to your friends if they have disabled this feature ;)

Comment: Just FYI... Blue iMessages will still say "delivered" when the messages arrives on the other phone.  If Read Receipts are turned off, then the word delivered will never change to "read".

Comment: I get the identical problem to the original user (mine says "read" if they read it but never "delivered") and I definitely tested the other phone (my wife's) to make sure this setting was not in effect on it.

Comment: Yeah, read receipts have nothing to with the delivered message. I say try checking your internet. Sometimes mine will deliver but the message comes up a little later.